asyncapi - generate kafka topic commands?
Within the asyncapi cli tool is there a way to generate the commands needed to create the kafka topics what the event driven application needs.
asyncapi generate . . .

I'd hope that this would generate a set of command line statements in this format
kafka-topics.sh --create --topic 'topic-name-per-async-api-yml'

which the developer would then run to create the topics they need.
Thanks
Reference:

Kafka topic creation command


Good question. As I know, no, for now you can't generate list of shells to create topics
I see two options:

Open issue in our repo with feature request
Create your own template, and use it for shells generation

